# Capture photo with a different dimension than displayed

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation

I try to capture picture from a iPhone with AVFoundation but I have some troubles to find what I need.
I created a AVCaptureSession and add preset to AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh.
`self.session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;`

I display the videoPreviewLayer in my view and I can capture the picture with the code:

```
AVCapturePhotoSettings *settings = [AVCapturePhotoSettings photoSettingsWithFormat: @{AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG}];
[self.stillImageOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:settings delegate:self]
```

And I get a FHD picture (1920x1080), so this works well.

But now I want to keep a good displayed picture, so keep the preset high but capture picture with the resolution 640x480.

Is it possible?
Any ideas?

---

I tried this:

```
NSDictionary *outputSetting = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1280], (id)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithDouble:960], (id)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
                               nil];

AVCapturePhotoSettings *settings = [AVCapturePhotoSettings photoSettingsWithFormat: outputSetting];

[self.stillImageOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:settings delegate:(id)self];
```

But I get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[AVCapturePhotoSettings photoSettingsWithFormat:] Unsupported keys specified: {(
    Height,
    Width
)}. Supported keys are {(
    PixelFormatType
)}'
```

Comment: “keep the preset high but capture picture with the resolution 640x480“ Unclear what those words are supposed to mean. What is the real goal here?

Comment: because i need the aspect ration 4:3 and the resolution 640x480 to process images after. But i want to display the camera preview on the entire screen (iphone 8) so 1920x1080.

Comment: The preset has nothing to do with how the camera preview is displayed. If you want to produce a thumbnail of a certain size, you can ask for that.

Comment: But when i change the preset to 640x480, the preview is deformed by the videoGravity. I think i don't understand something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are preparing to take the photo, request a 640x480 secondary output, like this:

```
let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
let pbpf = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes[0]
settings.previewPhotoFormat = [
    kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : pbpf,
    kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String : 640,
    kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String : 480
```

When you take the photo, pass the `settings` in, like this:

```
output.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
```

The secondary output will come back to you as the photo’s `previewCGImageRepresentation` in the delegate method.

Comment: This is Swift, of course, but I’m sure you can translate to Objective-C.

Comment: I tried this, like it's written in the question,but i make a mistake on the question it's now solve, sorry about that ^^

Comment: If you trivially solved the original problem, feel free to delete the question.